# Save as Pdf with TOC

Tags: excel-2007

In Excel 2007 you can save a workbook as pdf which produces a nice pdf document that can have custom headers and footers.

If my workbook has 12 sheets for example with sales in January through December it would be nice to be able to save this as pdf with an automatic table of contents that references each month. Therefore when you open the pdf document you can use hyperlinks to navigate to the point in the document (month) that you want.

Is this possible using the save as pdf excel feature? or how else can it be done.Is there any third party software that can be called from VBA to maybe create a pdf and do this automatically? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I have in mind involves using .NET. But then you mentioned VBA, so I figured you might be willing to go through that route.
Using VSTO create a managed add-in (e.g.: C# and Excel's object model). Using C# (.Net in general) you'd have many more options with PDF generators.

Some useful links:

1. VSTO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx
2. One of the many PDF generator for .NET: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: Ill look into your suggestions. I was hoping there would be an easier way. Thanks Amir.

Comment: Well, if this is something you don't do often and don't need automation, then other suggestions work better. I only thought that you'd want to automate because you mentioned VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give this a try http://exceltopdf.org/
I tried to convert a 2 sheet excel document, and got nice output

**Update 1**

In order to have all the individual sheets printed within a single PDF file (not multiple PDFs) you need to set the same page setup options for all of them (page setup in Excel modifies the print size of the resulting file, so for example if you set the page layout to landscape in Excel, the printed page will be landscape but your original Excel file will still maintain the same view).

To set the same Page Setup options for all individual Excel sheets:
Open the Excel workbook 
Right-click the tab for any of the sheets you have in your workspace (by default the sheet-tabs are named Sheet1, Sheet2, etc...) 
Choose the Select all Sheets option (which will select all the sheets in your workspace, you can tell they're selected if all the sheet tabs have a white background, like an active sheet tab would have) 
Go to File->Page Setup, select the options you want for the resulting printed pages (it's important that the Print Quality is the same for all pages) and press OK so that Excel will record the fact that all pages have the same print settings. It's important to press the OK button even if you don't change anything, because this will "tell" Excel that all the sheets have the same page setup options. 
Go to File->Print Preview and see if you like the way the pages will show when printed to PDF. If you don't have any changes to the printing options go to File->Print, select the Entire Workbook option under Print What and PDF XChange from the Printer name section and click OK to create the PDF file 
PDF XChange will ask you where to save the PDF and (if the option is set) it will open the PDF when it's created.

Source: http://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/185-How-do-I-make-Excel-print-several-sheets-in-a-single-PDF

**Update 2**
And even if that does not solve the problem then have a look at these: http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltools/qt/10-02-06-create-pdf-file-excel-2010.htm, http://www.novapdf.com/kb/printing-an-entire-excel-workbook-to-a-single-pdf-file-135.html

Comment: I want to use this for work so uploading sensitive data to an online program is not an option. There surely has to be an easy way to do this with VBA

Comment: I have been able to print to pdf in the past but what I am trying to do is print a pdf that has a navigation bar or table of contents. At the moment I just use the save as pdf option in excel and it creates a pdf but you cant navigate the pdf easily. In word you can insert a table of contents that makes navigation easy and I was hoping there was something similar when printing to pdf with excel. Thanks

Comment: @Kharoof So why did you say for the 1st answer that i cannot upload, even if you upload that, the result it will generate, you dont want that right? the pdf that is generated by the website does not satisfy your needs too right? there are no self generated table of contents in that... Am I right?

Comment: I have asked this question as I want to use this for work. The workbooks I will be converting to pdf may contain sensitive data I cannot use any third party online conversion tools such as the website in your 1st answer. I need a native microsoft or simple vba code solution. Its possible that what I am looking for is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create an extra sheet in your workbook, which contains 12 hyperlinks (to other sheets).

   - You can do it manually (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/create-a-table-of-contents-in-an-excel-sheet-using-hyperlinks/).
   - You can create macro for it (http://blogs.office.com/2011/01/13/add-a-table-of-contents-to-your-workbook-its-easy-i-promise/).

     AFAIK, you can create a macro that will create TOC sheet, then call export-to-pdf menu item, then drop TOC sheet. But do you need it? The easiest way is just to create TOC sheet manually.
2. When exporting to PDF using OpenOffice, it *automatically creates bookmark for each sheet*. (Doesn't MS Office 2007 Excel do the same? Or you really need links instead of bookmarks, don't you?)

Comment: I tried this at work today with excel 2007. It didnt create hyperlinks on each page of the pdf. Any other ideas?

Comment: I didn't know that you want TOC on EACH page. I thought adding TOC on first page is enough. Question: Do you really need links? Aren't you satisfied with bookmarks?

Comment: IMO I should return bounty somehow as I understood your question incorrectly.

Comment: I have other ideas. But they're non-trivial to implement.

Comment: If you really need links (not bookmarks) -- I have other ideas. But they're non-trivial to implement.

Comment: I want a TOC with links or just bookmarks so that it is easy to navigate the document. If I create an index (TOC) page with links in the workbook I can navigate the workbook but when I print to pdf the links just show as text and you cannot click on them. Its possible this is not possible (easily) but if it is I would appreciate your help.